# Run a ATL COM DLL from a Browser (call a method)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, com, activex, atl

I have a COM Object created using ATL (without MFC Support)

The Object has 1 method that opens a Dialog (that does all the rest)

Currently I call it from another EXE:

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_MyControl,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IMyControl,
    (void**) &pMyControl
    );
```

and then:

```
hr = pMyControl->MyMethod (ATL::CComBSTR(InputString1), ATL::CComBSTR(InputString2), &IntReturned, &IntReturned);
```

Is it possible to call it as is from a browser ?

How can I Instantiate the object and invoke my method (with params) from the browser ?

Comment: In IE? In any browser?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this from IE or a `WebBrowser`-based app, but not from any other browser (not without separate plugins).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points to answer your question:

- You won't be able to use a COM object in any browser other than IE or a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-based app.
- You'd need to implement [IObjectSafety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to allow IE to create your object. Naturally, the object should be safe for scripting by any untrusted source. Ideally, you should [lock the object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to your own list of sites. You could use [SiteLock](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=23438) template for this.
- The object should implement `IDispatch` interface, to be available for scripting. The best way is to use ATL's `IDispatchImpl` (most likely, it's already done in your code).
- The `MyMethod` in your sample uses two `[out]` arguments for `IntReturned`. JavaScript only allows one output `[out, retval]` argument. If you need to return more than one value, you'd have to use VBScript.

Example (substitute your CLSID):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/vbscript">
        Option Explicit
        window.onload = GetRef("OnLoadHandler")

        Sub OnLoadHandler
            Dim InputString1
            Dim InputString2
            Dim IntReturned1
            Dim IntReturned2

            InputString1 = "a"  
            InputString1 = "b"  
            testObject.MyMethod InputString1, InputString2, IntReturned1, IntReturned

            alert "Result: " & IntReturned1 & ", " & IntReturned
        End Sub
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <object id="testObject" classid="clsid:12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890AB">
        <span>Unable to create the object.</span>
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't implement `IObjectSafety`, you can still run this code as HTML Application. Save it as an .HTA file, and run as `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe C:\users\user\Documents\test.hta` if your C++ COM DLL is 32-bit, or as `C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe C:\users\user\Documents\test.hta` if it is 64-bit.

The COM DLL needs to be registered first with `regsvr32.exe` (you've probably already done this if you can use it from a C++ client project).

Comment: Another way is to create the object dynamically with VBScript's `testObject = CreateObject("YourComClass.ProgID")` or JavaScript's `var testObject = new ActiveXObject("YourComClass.ProgID")`.