# ActiveX ok from cmd but not working in web page

Tags: javascript, activex

I have a script to create an ActiveX component that works fine when run from the command line but reports:
SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object

when run from JavaScript in a html page. I know the web page JavaScript works OK when I try and create a different ActiveX component like Excel.Application so I think it is something about the particular ActiveX component I am trying to create.

How can I debug this? Id there some flag I can check to see if the ActiveX component will not allow itself to be created in a web page?

The web page JavaScript looks like this:

```
<script language="javascript" >
        function MakeOne()
        {
            var obj = new ActiveXObject('ECRUtilATL.Transaction');
            obj.Amount1In = "12.53";

            var result = "";
            if (obj == null) {
                result = 'null';
            }
            else {
                result = 'not null';
            }
            alert(result);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19329800/1768303

Comment: That has started me down the right track - thanks